# unable to launch digitally signed exe

Tags: c#, exe, digital-signature

I have a .net windows application, I am not able to launch the output exe when I digitally sign the exe but I am able to launch it when I don't have digital signature on the same. I have used signtool.exe for digital signing

Comment: Do you see valid signature from exe-file properties in Explorer?

Comment: Instructions unclear; please add detail. In what way does it fail? Any error messages?

Comment: @i486 - yes there is valid signature in properties

Comment: @MatthewWatson : Just the exe doesn't launch, there is no error in event viewer and I have signed a different exe with same certificate and I am able to launch it. Moreover I have tried debugging the code of exe but the debugger is not reaching the Main function. I am able to debug it if I remove the certificates.

Comment: I have checked the signing logs as well it says operation completed successfully

Comment: Try on different PC. What is the OS?

Comment: Tried on different PC too. Trying to launch exe on Windows 7 Professional